# Computing $2016$ using basic operations on the fewest integers, in sequence

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Using the operators $$+,-,\div,\times,\exp,(,),!$$ what is the least $n$  to come up with the number $2016$ using the sequence of numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,n$ in that order. You cannot combine numbers, so you cannot do $2~~3=23$ and you cannot negate values.

My solution consists of $10$ numbers. I want to see if someone can come up with the least use of operators in their answer.

Good luck! If no one is able to get less than $10$ numbers, I will post my answer.

Comment: Can you use unary minus to negate numbers?

Comment: No you cannot negate numbers in any way

Comment: I am asking for the least number $n$ using any operator to get 2016.

Comment: $exp$ is "to the power of"?

Comment: @shoover Yes, like 2^3=8

Comment: So something like $((1 + 2) * 3 ^ {4!})$ would be valid if it equaled 2016, but not $1 ^ {-2}$.

Comment: @shoover correct

Comment: Is it fair to do something like $1-(2-3) \times 4$?

Comment: @ChadShin sure, that;s fine

Comment: Related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25039/5095 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1595709/18398

Comment: $2016$ is the smallest number of the form $2^{a+b}~\Big(2^{ab}-1\Big),$ with *a* and *b* distinct primes.

Answer (score 7):

$4$ number solution:
$$\left((1+2)!\right)!+(3!)^4=2016$$

Comment: Bravo.... surely unsurpassable.  So how'd you find it?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Carefully

Comment: I was going to write a *Mathematica* program to search.  But from now on I guess I should just be "careful" as that suffices!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If you don't mind, I would like to see the Mathematica program.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork There may be other variations of this solution, but I doubt there is anything less than $4$.

Comment: I just started to write it when your answer appeared, so I realized it wasn't worth my time.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sounds fair

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a 9 number solution.

$1-(2!\times 3! \times 4! \times (5-6) \times 7) +8-9=2016$

I have the feeling that this is not the smallest one, but this is the smallest I can find at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 7-number solution:

$((1 + 2 * 3) * 4! - 5!) * 6 * 7$