# Finding the altitude(s) of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

In light of [that problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594740/v-i-arnold-says-russian-students-cant-solve-this-problem-but-american-student/1594935#1594935), I would like to offer my version. It could have puzzled both the American and Russian students:-

ABCD is a parallelogram with the lengths of the 2 adjacent sides being 5 cm and 10 cm. If one the altitude is 8 cm, what could be the length of the other altitude(s)

(a)     4 cm

(b)     16 cm

(c)     4 cm or 16 cm

(d)     none of the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area of a parallelogram is the "base" times the "height." Each base has its own height, but the area will be the same whichever base you choose.

If the altitude (height) of $8$ cm goes with the side $5$ cm, then the area is $40$ square cm and the altitude on the side $10$ cm is $4$ cm.

If the altitude (height) of $8$ cm goes with the side $10$ cm, then the area is $80$ square cm and the altitude on the side $5$ cm is $16$ cm. **However,** we cannot have an altitude of $8$ cm if the other side is only $5$ cm (we would have a right triangle with leg $8$ and hypotenuse $5$), so this choice is not possible.

So the answer is (a), 4 cm.

Comment: just need to prove that both  parallelograms really exist. For the first one Kiran linsuain's sketch is good enough. Oh, you were faster :-)

Comment: @z100: Yes, I checked my first answer after I typed it in and saw that one parallelogram was not possible. I changed my answer before you typed your comment... but later than I should have. Better late than never!

Answer (score 0):

4 cm is the answer, the topmost angle is equal to the bottom one, this implies that the triangles are similar.
[image: explanation]

Also, area is altitude times side length and 4x10=5x8.