# Tangent of a circle through a point not on circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

> Given the equation of a circle: $(x+4)^2+(y-2)^2 = 1$ find the tangent that goes through the point $(-3,3)$…

…but this point IS NOT on this circle. Unfortunately, this is not something that I have seen before and the normal formula doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: There are exactly two such tangents. As a hint, recall that the lines are perpendicular if and only if the products of their slopes is $-1$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 But the given point is _in_ the circle. Thus there are no tangents at all.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Holy cow, you're right, the point is in the circle! Then this question makes no sense. There must be an error in the exercise.

Comment: See also [this famous ill-posed question from Vladimir Arnold](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1594740/357390).

Comment: One way to show (-3,3) is in the circle is to plug the coordinates in. Since the point (1 000 000, 1 000 000) has a value greater than 0, points inside the circle have values less than 0. Since the value of the expression with (-3,3) is -9, the point is therefore inside the circle.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: He would have fooled me I guess, it's a fun fact though.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel OH NO! this is a little embarrasing, but i made a typo. its supposed to be 1 not 11 (my keyboard is terrible). I'm very sorry and i will try my best to proof read my work better!

Comment: @JohnHon I'll have the question solved now.

Comment: And did you type the point correctly?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes i doubled checked, a tangent through (-3,3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little graphing won't hurt:
[image]
By inspection, the tangent lines are $x=-3$ and $y=3$.

Comment: yeah this is what i gathered from my teacher. However is this the only way? what if the line was not vertical or horizontal though?

Comment: @JohnHon The idea when finding a tangent generally is to consider the right-angled triangle between the circle centre, the point in question and the point of tangency. A little wringing of algebra then obtains the tangent lines; I suggest you search Stack Exchange (yes, this site) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a formula you could use:

$$(y-b)=m(x-a)\pm r\sqrt{1+m^2}$$

for a circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$

Although  (3,3) ain't giving you a tangent

Answer (score -1):

You should have a system of equation the first is the circle and the second is the general equation for a line that pass from $(3,3)$ substitute one into the others and apply the tangent condition $b^2-4ac=0$ you will find the two points. Another methods is using the derivation.

Comment: The point $(-3,3)$ is inside the circle so there are no tangents which pass through this point - this method will give erroneous solutions

Comment: It will give a non real  solution