# What to do in this case when applying the law of sinus? I get an error 2 message.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to applying the law of sinus in this triangle to get the angle of A. However when I do that I find myself having to do the $sin^{-1} 1.59$ to get A.

This is obtained by having $\dfrac{22}{A} = \dfrac{12}{60}$.

The problem is that it does not work $sin^{-1} 1.59$ gives me a an error 2 message on my calculator.
How can I get the angle A if this does not work.

[image: triangle where I want to apply the law of sinus]

Comment: You should have $30^°$ instead of $60^°$.

Comment: You need to draw in the nostrils to use the law of sinus.  =)

Comment: This question is a variation on [a famous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594740/v-i-arnold-says-russian-students-cant-solve-this-problem-but-american-student) on this site.

Answer (score 7):

By the law of sines,
$$
\frac{22}{\sin A}=\frac{12}{\sin 60^\circ}
$$
which yields
$$
\sin A = \frac{11\sqrt{3}}{12}\approx 1.59$$
contradiction, since $\sin A$ can't be greater than $1$.

What it means is that there is no such triangle (i.e., it's a trick question).

To further explain, note that the perpendicular distance from the point $J$ to the line $EA$ is $11\sqrt{3}$ which is more than $12$.

The diagram below visually illustrates the issue . . .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach:

Let side $AE$ be $x$. By the law of cosines,

$$\cos 60º = \frac{22^2 + x^2 - 12^2}{2(22)(x)}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} = \frac{340+x^2}{44x}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{22x}{44x} = \frac{340+x^2}{44x}$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2-22x+340=0 \tag{$x \ne 0$}$$

This has discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = (-22)^2 - 4(3)(340) < 0$. Therefore, there is no possible value of $AE$ that satisfies the conditions in the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

When two sides are given along with an angle  *not included* between them ( $60^ {\circ}$ is not given between sides $12$ and $22$),

there are three possible situations:

[image]

Let the length of normal be $JX=22\sin 60^{\circ}= 19.05$ approximately.

1) The third side length equals $JX$ in the construction of triangle there is tangential contact at $X$, and two points are coincident.

2) If the side side length $12$ is shorter than $JX$, then real solutions *do not exist,* as happened in this case.

3) When the given length is more than normal length then there would be *two* solutions to take (like the two small red circles), it cannot be decided which... it is an *ambiguous case.*