Solving an already solved question in Geometry leads to no real results
Two identical squares were attached to the edge of a cube.
Given:
$$
\text{AB} \cdot \text{BC} = 8.5 \\
\text{AD} = \sqrt{8}
$$
What is the volume of the cube?


My straight-forward answer:
Having:
$$
\text{AD} = \sqrt{8} \\
\text{AB} = x \\ 
\text{BC} = y \\ 
x \cdot y = 8.5
$$
We have two equations:
$$
x^2 + y^2 = \left( \sqrt{8} \right )^2 = 8 \\
x \cdot y = 8.5 \iff 2xy = 17 
$$
Thus adding both together:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = \left ( x + y \right )^2 = 17 + 8 = 25 \\
x + y = 5 
$$
And the volume is $ (x+y)^3 $ thus it's $5^3 = 125$

The post-answer question
Ok, having the answer that each edge is equal to 5 I wanted to find the exact values of $x$ and $y$, we know from the previous answer that $x+y = 5$, so we can have this system of equations:
$$
 \left\{\begin{matrix}
xy = 8.5 &  \\
x+y = 5&  \\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
This simplified down to this equation:
$$
y = \frac{8.5}{x} \\
x + \frac{8.5}{x} = 5 \\
x^2 + 8.5 = 5x \\
x^2 - 5x + 8.5 = 0
$$
Which doesn't yield any real solutions for $x$ thus neither not for $y$.
My question is simple - what am I doing wrong here? I am surely missing something, thanks!

You aren't doing anything wrong. I think this just means the original setup was flawed: it simply can't exist.

Notice too that $(x-y)^2=-9$

Makes me think of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594740

The original data given is wrong. Assuming that is originally correct, you should arrive at
$$(x+y) = 5 \qquad \text{and} \qquad (xy) = 8.5.$$
You did this much correctly. Now, looking at this, we see there can't be any solution to this equation. The maximum product that can be achieved from $x$ and $y$ is $6.25$, obtained by setting each of them as $2.5$.
To prove this, plot the graph of $x(5-x)$, which is essentially the graph of $xy$; you will see it has its vertex at $(2.5, 6.25)$.
Hence, $x$ and $y$ can't have a product of $8.25$, implying that the original given data is wrong.
