# Are all non-irrational numbers rational?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am working on a simple proof involving rational and irrational numbers. Is it safe to assume that if a number is not rational, it is irrational, and that if a number is not irrational, it is rational?

Example: Let $P(x)=\text{x is rational}$ and $Q(x)=\text{x is irrational}$.

Then is it true that $\forall x\ P(x)\text{ xor }Q(x)$?

Comment: A double negation is an affirmation.

Comment: As long as by "number" you mean *real* number.

Comment: I feel that it's important to point out that double negation isn't always an affirmation. See constructive mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real numbers are composed of the rational numbers and the irrational numbers so yes if a number is not one, it is the other.

See Dominik's answer:

[Are there real numbers that are neither rational nor irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435312/are-there-real-numbers-that-are-neither-rational-nor-irrational)

There he provided this excellent picture:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A rational number is defined as a number that can be expressed as the ratio of two integers, i.e. $\frac{p}{q}$, where $q\ne0$. An irrational number is a real number that cannot be expressed as a ratio. So, yes a real number is either rational or irrational, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

An irrational number is a number that is not rational.

Thus a non-irrational number is not (a number that is not rational), thus it is rational.

In set notation irrational numbers are $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, so non-irrational numbers are $\mathbb{R}\setminus(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}$.